# Rotating a Rectangle on an Image using Swing

Tags: java, swing

Ok when a user draws a Rectangle on top of an image, I want to find all the rotated Rectangles ahead of time for all image rotation angles (90,180,270,360).

According to Java API I can just keep calling the Graphics2D rotate() method.  I can then use this Graphics2D transformer to get the rotated Rectangle.

This works for the very first rotation(1.5708) call.  I get the correct Rectangle Point.  All other calls after that return the wrong Rectangle Point after using Transformer.

I think my problem is the Graphics2D translate(x,y).  I don't understand how to use it.

Anyone knows how to fix my code so that it will return the correct Rectangle after every rotation?

Thank you.

```
public void rotateRectangles(BufferedImage bim,int width,int height,Rectangle rect){
   BufferedImage bim = new BufferedImage(height, width,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) (bufferedImage.createGraphics());
   g2d.translate(bufferedImage.getHeight(),0); 

   //Get Rectangle for 90 degree image rotation. This always good.
   g2d.rotate(1.5708);
   Shape shape = g2d.getTransform().createTransformedShape(rect); 
   Rectangle rotatedRect = shape.getBounds(); 
   System.out.println("rotated rectangle at 90 degrees.  Point x="+rotatedRect.x+"  y="+rotatedRect.y);


   //Get Rectangle for 180 degree image rotation. Getting wrong rotatedRect.
   g2d.rotate(1.5708);
   shape = g2d.getTransform().createTransformedShape(rect); 
   rotatedRect = shape.getBounds(); 
   System.out.println("rotated rectangle at 180 degrees. Point x="+rotatedRect.x+"  y="+rotatedRect.y); 


  //Get Rectangle for 270 degree image rotation. Getting wrong rotatedRect.
   g2d.rotate(1.5708);
   shape = g2d.getTransform().createTransformedShape(rect); 
   rotatedRect = shape.getBounds(); 
   System.out.println("rotated rectangle at 270 degrees. Point x="+rotatedRect.x+"  y="+rotatedRect.y);


  //Get Rectangle for 360 degree image rotation.Getting wrong rotatedRect.
   g2d.rotate(1.5708);
   shape = g2d.getTransform().createTransformedShape(rect); 
   rotatedRect = shape.getBounds(); 
   System.out.println("rotated rectangle at 360 degrees. Point x="+rotatedRect.x+"  y="+rotatedRect.y);
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: What is it returning and what are you expecting?

Comment: I need an actual Rectangle object for all 90,180,270,360 degrees. Just trying to create the Rectangles ahead of time for all rotations.

Comment: yes, but what is the code outputting the second time and what are you expecting specifically.

Comment: I modified my question. Previous was too confusing. After the first rotation the Rectangles have the wrong Point(x,y).  The Height and Width are ok thou.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rotating the graphics context's affine transform via `g2d.rotate()`, consider using  `createTransformedShape()` as suggested in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/point-in-polygon).

Addendum: Note in particular that the baseline of the example `Polygon` is initially centered on the origin. As a result, the initial transformation is rotation around the origin. In your case, you can use the [`rotate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#rotate%28double,%20double,%20double%29) method that includes an anchor point, which would be the center of your rectangle.