# transforming Rectangle2D java

Tags: java, swing, transform

I am trying to rotate a Rectangle2D object by a particular theta. But I cannot do this because the method transform(AffineTransform) is undefined for Rectangle2D. Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks.

```
Rectangle2D.Double currentVehic = new Rectangle2D.Double(bottomLeft[0], bottomLeft[1],vehicWidth, vehicHeight);
    // Rotate the vehicle perimeter about its center
    AffineTransform rotate = new AffineTransform();
    //Rectangle2D rotatedVehic = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(theta,x,y);
    rotate.setToRotation(theta, x, y);
    currentVehic.transform(rotate);

    return currentVehic;
```

Answer (score 6):

Because a `Rectangle2D` is a `Shape`, you may be looking for the `AffineTransform` method [`createTransformedShape()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape-java.awt.Shape-). A complete example is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594424/230513), and another is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5111336/230513).