# Using AffineTransform on a Rectangle

Tags: java

I am trying to create a simple rectangle using an AffineTransform. Here is kinda what I am wanting to do...

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.transform(width/2, height/2);

switch(direction){
case 1:
     return new Rectangle(at, width, height);
case 2:
     return new Rectangle(at, width*2, height*2);
}
```

I'm not sure how, or if you can, create a rectangle using an AffineTransform. If anyone knows how to do this please share your information.

Comment: [A quick glance at the `Rectangle` Javadoc suggests that you can't pass in an `AffineTransform` as an argument to the constructor.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)  You may be best served by extracting the bits you need from the `AffineTransform` and plug them into the `Rectangle` directly.

Comment: Try `createTransformedShape()`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23644698/230513).

Answer (score 1):

After applying an `AffineTransform`, a `Rectangle` is no longer necessarily an ordinary `Rectangle`. A `Rectangle` however derives from `Rectangle2D` which implements `Shape`.

And an AffineTransform can transform a Shape into a new `Shape` with its [`createTransformedShape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape%28java.awt.Shape%29) method.

That's a best way to go about it, if you want the full power of `AffineTransform`. You can draw a `Shape`, test whether points fall inside or outside it, turn it into an `Area`, etc.