# Finding scale factor by dragging the mouse - Scale a shape in java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a shape and a vector of shape's points, and I want to zoom in/out (resize whatever) the shape by dragging the mouse from a point of the shape to other random point (like in windows point for example)

What I search e read is that to scale a shape you have to recalculate all coordinates to:

**xScaled = firstX * scaleX**

**yScaled = firstY * sclaleY**

My problem is how to find that scale factor, what is the formula? Remebering that I have acess to the firstHitPoint, the actual point and all the points of the shape, and I have to do this by dragging the mouse.

Here is a peaceof my code:

```
@Override
public void transformPoints() {
    findTransformationFactors();

    int size = points.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        points.set(i, new Point(points.get(i).x * scaleX, points.get(i).y * scaleY));

}

@Override
public void findTransformationFactors() {
    int oldx = firstHitPoint.x;
    int oldY = firstHitPoint.y;

    int actualX = actualPoint.x;
    int actualY = actualPoint.y;

    scaleX = ??
    scaleY = ??

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).  In this case it would provide a template to allow people to play with ideas.

Comment: Use `createTransformedShape()` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23644698/230513)

Answer (score 0):

The X factor taking the center as a constant point:

```
xVar = (initial.getX()-mouse.getX())/(center.getX()-initial.getX());
scaleX=xVar+1.0;
```

Then you must control that the scale applied is not negative --> avoid mirror transform